# how to create or update multiple tables using Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, express, sequelize.js

I'm working on developing back-end with DB using Sequelize ORM. I need to create data into multiple tables or update data into multiple tables. but I'm not sure how to do this. those are example of mine below:

```
//Tables
const main = sequelize.define('main', {
id: {type: Sequelize.STRING, primaryKey: true},
column1: Sequelize.STRING,
column2: Sequelize.STRING,
column3: Sequelize.STRING,
}, {
tableName: 'main'
});

const table1 = sequelize.define('table1', {
column1: Sequelize.STRING,
column2: Sequelize.STRING,
column3: Sequelize.STRING,
mainId: Sequelize.STRING,
}, {
tableName: 'table1'
});

const table2 = sequelize.define('table1', {
column1: Sequelize.STRING,
column2: Sequelize.STRING,
column3: Sequelize.STRING,
mainId: Sequelize.STRING,
}, {
tableName: 'table2'
});

//relation with tables
table1.belongsTo(MAIN, {foreignKey: 'mainId'});
MAIN.hasMany(table1, {foreignKey: 'mainId'});
table2.belongsTo(MAIN, {foreignKey: 'mainId'});
MAIN.hasMany(table2, {foreignKey: 'mainId'});
table3.belongsTo(MAIN, {foreignKey: 'mainId'});
MAIN.hasMany(table3, {foreignKey: 'mainId'});

//Input Body(JSON)
{
"id": "MAIN0001",
"column1": "string",
"column1": "string",
"column3": "string",
"table1": {
  "column1": "string",
  "column2": "string",
  "column3": "string",
  "mainId": "MAIN0001",
  },
"table1": {
  "column1": "string",
  "column2": "string",
  "column3": "string",
  "mainId": "MAIN0001",
  },
"table2": {
  "column1": "string",
  "column2": "string",
  "column3": "string"
  "mainId": "MAIN0001",
  }
}
```

That's all example of what I'm gonna do.
Plz let me know how can I do this.

Thxs in advance :D

Answer (score 0):

There a quite a few ways. Here are a few

**Using transactions**

```
try {

  const result = await sequelize.transaction(async (t) => {

    const createdMain = await main1.create({
      column1: 'string',
      column2: 'string',
      column3: 'string',
    }, { transaction: t });

    const createdTable1 = await table1.create({
      column1: 'string',
      column2: 'string',
      column3: 'string',
      mainId: createdMain.id
    }, { transaction: t });

    return {
      ...createdMain,
     table1: createdTable1,
    };
  });

} catch (error) {

  // If the execution reaches this line, an error occurred.
  // The transaction has already been rolled back automatically by Sequelize!

}
```

**Creating main and table1 in one step:**

```
return main1.create({
   column1: 'string',
   column2: 'string',
   column3: 'string',
   table1: {
     column1: 'string',
     column2: 'string',
     column3: 'string',
   },
   // Repeat for table 2 and table 3
}, {
    include: [ table1 ]
  // Include table 2 and table 3
  }]
});
```

Comment: Oh thx to answer :) BTW I’m curious about it. Is it possible to create data rows in tables with 1:N relation as well?

Comment: Like creating a `main1` data from a `table1` @Christopher ?